# how to create an array of values from an existing array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which has many objects, I want to make an array of `tag` values so I can display the non repeated tags in the frontend.
This is the array, and from which I want to create the new array which will include all the `tag` values.

[image]

Can you please share with me a solution or maybe a way to solve this ? Thanks

Comment: `object.nodes.map(({ tag }) => tag)`?

Comment: Also see: [Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array#map` to get all the tag property values, and then create a `Set` from that to get the unique ones.

```js
const tags = [...new Set(yourObj.nodes.map(x => x.tag))];
```

Comment: It doesnt display the unique ones

Comment: @YaakoubiMohammed What is it displaying? What is the input?

Comment: `  {new Set(allArticles.nodes.map((x : any) =>
  (
    <AbsoluteLink to='/python'>{'>'}{x.tag}</AbsoluteLink>

  )
  ))}`

Comment: it displays all the tags

Comment: @YaakoubiMohammed If you want to have the unique array of the components, you need to first get the array with the unique values and then use `.map()` to map it to components `[...new Set(yourObj.nodes.map(x => x.tag))].map((tag) => ( <AbsoluteLink to='/python'>{'>'}{tag}</AbsoluteLink> ) )`